# FormatM -> IO Double

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use getRealTime function from Test.Hspec.Formatters to return a Double value (or IO Double - something that I can print the to the screen for example):

Here's the getRealTime definition:

```
getRealTime :: FormatM Double
getRealTime = do
  t1 <- liftIO getPOSIXTime
  t0 <- gets startTime
  return (realToFrac $ t1 - t0)

newtype FormatM a = FormatM (StateT (IORef FormatterState) IO a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)
```

I am looking for an example of code that implements this:

```
getTime :: FormatM Double -> IO Double
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately what you want to do isn't possible with the current version of the library (1.9.5 at time of writing). The `Test.Hspec` library doesn't export the `FormatM` constructor, nor any methods to convert the `FormatM a` to `IO a`.

The closest function is `runFormatM` in the `Test.Hspec.Formatters.Internal` module:

There is the function:

```
runFormatM :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> Integer -> Handle -> FormatM a -> IO a
runFormatM useColor produceHTML_ printCpuTime seed handle (FormatM action) = do
  time <- getPOSIXTime
  cpuTime <- if printCpuTime then Just <$> CPUTime.getCPUTime else pure Nothing
  st <- newIORef (FormatterState handle useColor produceHTML_ False 0 0 0 [] seed cpuTime time)
  evalStateT action st
```

However it isn't exposed by the package making it inaccessible.